# How can I center the text element inside <g> element?

Tags: javascript, svg

This is the structure of my SVG

```
<g id="CDT-B6-2">
   <path id="CDT-B6-box"/>
   <text x="1210" y="993" id="CDT-B6-text">888</text>
</g>
```

Problems:

1. The `textContent` from text element is dynamic, it may shorter than length of 3
2. Inside my SVG I have many `<g id="CDT-B6-2">` but different ids & position
3. I used `x="50%" y="50%"` to all text elements but it didn't put the text alignment centered from `<g>` element

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dominant-baseline: middle` and `text-anchor: middle`:

```css
text {
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

rect {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="100">
  <g transform="translate(10 20)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="80" height="40" />
    <text x="40" y="20">888</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(110 40)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="80" height="40" />
    <text x="40" y="20">888888</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```